# Looking Through Multiple .csv Files with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to make an excel sheet that can look through a .csv file and then copy and paste certain information from that .csv file. I do not know anything about .csv files, but in this case, they look and act like an excel file.

Here is the code that currently looks through a single .csv file (20180426IM-RV0K6OQH5MA2.csv)

```
Sub finder()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:J200").Clear

'Use user deffined part number to locate the folder
Dim ParNum As String, FilePath As String, FileName As String
ParNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "D").Value
FilePath = "R:\Series\Serial No. AC710121\" & ParNum & "\20180426IM-RV0K6OQH5MA2.csv"

'Declare Variables populated excel sheet
Dim Book As Workbook
Dim Brange As Range
Dim Bcell

Set Book = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
Set Brange = Book.Sheets("20180426IM-RV0K6OQH5MA2").Range("A1:A200")

'Declare Variables for finder excel sheet
Dim Drange As Range
Dim Dcell

Set Drange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D5:D205")

'Declare Variables for finder excel sheet
Dim Crange As Range
Dim Ccell

Set Crange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C205")

'For loop for printing in Finder
For Each Bcell In Brange

If Bcell.Value = "IT" Then
    Book.Sheets("20180426IM-RV0K6OQH5MA2").Range(Bcell.Offset(0, 2), Bcell.Offset(0, 8)).Copy

    For Each Dcell In Drange
        If IsEmpty(Dcell.Value) = True And IsEmpty(Dcell.Offset(0, -1).Value) = True Then

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Dcell.Offset(0, 0), Dcell.Offset(0, 8)).PasteSpecial
        End If
     Next Dcell       
End If
Next Bcell


End Sub
```

The .csv files are automatically generated, and over time, there will be multiple .csv files in the folder. I would like the code to be able to open one .csv file, do its thing, then open the next .csv file and repeat until all the .csv files in the folder have been looked through.

Also, is there is a way to declare a variable as the name of the file being looked through and have the sheet in that file equal to the variable name? For example, if the file name is "Bob," I would like to declare a variable that is "Bob" in order to tell the code that the worksheet in this workbook is also called "Bob."

I hope this is clear enough. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that does what I was asking about correctly:

```
Sub finder()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:J200").Clear

'Use user deffined part number to locate the file
Dim ParNum As String, FilePath As String, FileName As String
ParNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "D").Value

'Variable that represents the file name
File = Dir("R:\Series\Serial No. AC710121\" & ParNum & "\*.csv")

'Looks through all the .csv files in the folder
Do While File <> ""

     'Variable that represents the name within the file
     SheetVar = Left(File, 23)
     'Variable that represents the file path to the file
     FilePath = "R:\Series\Serial No. AC710121\" & ParNum & "\" & File & ""

    'Declare Variables for populated excel sheet
    Dim Book As Workbook
    Dim Krange As Range
    Dim Kcell

    Set Book = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Set Krange = Book.Sheets(SheetVar).Range("A1:A200")

    'Declare Variables for finder excel sheet (Column D)
    Dim Drange As Range
    Dim Dcell

    Set Drange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D5:D205")

    'Declare Variables for finder excel sheet (Column C)
    Dim Crange As Range
    Dim Ccell

    Set Crange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C205")

    'For loop for copying the information and pasting it in Finder
    For Each Kcell In Krange

        If Kcell.Value = "IT" Then
            Book.Sheets(SheetVar).Range(Kcell.Offset(0, 2), Kcell.Offset(0, 8)).Copy

            For Each Dcell In Drange
                 If IsEmpty(Dcell.Value) = True And IsEmpty(Dcell.Offset(0, -1).Value) = True Then

                     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Dcell.Offset(0, 0), Dcell.Offset(0, 8)).PasteSpecial

                    If Dcell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "OK" Then
                        Range(Dcell.Offset(0, 0), Dcell.Offset(0, 6)).Interior.Color = RGB(113, 221, 131)
                    End If

                    If Dcell.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "OK" And IsEmpty(Dcell.Offset(0, 6).Value) = False Then
                        Range(Dcell.Offset(0, 0), Dcell.Offset(0, 6)).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 100, 120)
                    End If

                    Exit For

                 End If

            Next Dcell

        End If

        If Kcell.Value = "DA" Then
            Book.Sheets(SheetVar).Range(Kcell.Offset(0, 1), Kcell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy

            For Each Ccell In Crange
                If IsEmpty(Ccell.Value) = True And IsEmpty(Ccell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Ccell.Offset(0, 0), Ccell.Offset(0, 0)).PasteSpecial
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Ccell

        End If

    Next Kcell

    Workbooks(File).Close SaveChanges = False

    File = Dir

Loop

Range("C2:J200").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
'Range("F5:F200").Sort Key1:=Range("F5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

I'm sorry if some of the variables are different, but this should be able to highlight the changes that I implemented to get the code to do what I want. I assume there is a more elegant way to go about doing this task, this is just what I came up with.

This code is able to do the following:

It takes a user provided part number, then uses that number to find a folder and then looks through each .csv file in said folder. It goes through the .csv files and copies certain information and then pastes it into the workbook in which the code is saved.

Hope this can help someone down the line.